# Button to perform action before window shows xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, onclick

I'm trying to get a button (on click) to show a hidden radio button `rbChoice2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible`. The radio button is on another window which required another button save_Click to show the window and send a value to the radio button content. So I need the first button to had already made the radio button visible before the save_Click is clicked.

I'm very new to WPF, although I've tried putting the visibility code and content code in the first button and it doesn't work. Here is the code I've tried.

```
public partial class Create : Window
{

    public Create()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void addChoice1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        choice2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        addChoice2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        addChoice1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Save obj = new Save();
        obj.rbChoice2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        obj.rbChoice2.Content = choice2.Text;


    }

    private void save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Save objS = new Save();
        objS.lbTest.Content = question.Text;
        objS.rbChoice1.Content = choice1.Text;
        objS.rbChoice2.Content = choice2.Text;
        objS.ShowDialog();

    }
```

}

Here is a picture of this does: [As the Add Choice button is clicked, another textbox is made visible under the first one and so at the same time another radio button should be made visible in the Save window but it doesn't work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhQRb.png)

I'm learning xaml while coding so I hope I asked the question right and understandably. Really hope someone can help with this. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 copies of the window - "obj" and "objS" are not related at all.

Try this:

```
public partial class Create : Window
{

public Create()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

Save obj = new Save();

private void addChoice1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    choice2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    addChoice2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    addChoice1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

    obj.rbChoice2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    obj.rbChoice2.Content = choice2.Text;
}

private void save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    obj.lbTest.Content = question.Text;
    obj.rbChoice1.Content = choice1.Text;
    obj.rbChoice2.Content = choice2.Text;
    obj.ShowDialog();
}

}
```

Comment: Yes I tried that before and it gave me this exception error: https://gyazo.com/2fd8a9c5ab93049055c021abe06ee7e8

Comment: A StackOverflowException usually means you have some kind of infinite loop happening.

Comment: Apologies, didn't realise pressing enter would submit my comment. Are you doing anything in the Loaded event for your "Save" window that could cause this?   Try putting a breakpoint on the "Save obj = new Save();" line, and press F11 in Visual Studio after it's been hit to step through youre code a line at the time, and see if you can figure out why the inifite loop is happening.

Comment: Thank you that worked. Sorry it was minimal, just wasn't sure why it wasn't working :)